# How to use SQL using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to optimise the performance of a query in Active Record. Previously I would do two SQL queries and it should be possible to do it in one.

These are the tables that I am running the queries on:

```
# Table name: notifications
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  content    :text(65535)
#  position   :integer

# Table name: dismissed_notifications
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  notification_id :integer
#  user_id         :integer
```

This is the existing query:

```
where.not(id: user.dismissed_notifications.pluck(:id))
```

which produces:

```
SELECT `dismissed_notifications`.`id` FROM `dismissed_notifications` WHERE `dismissed_notifications`.`user_id` = 655

SELECT  `notifications`.* FROM `notifications` WHERE (`notifications`.`id` != 1)
```

This is the SQL I would like to get, which returns the same records:

```
select *
from notifications n
where not exists(
    select 1
    from dismissed_notifications dn
    where dn.id = n.id
      and dn.user_id = 655)
```

Comment: Looks like a task for `outer_join` to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write `not exists` Query like below

```
where('NOT EXISTS (' + user.dismissed_notifications.where('dismissed_notifications.id = notifications.id').to_sql + ')')
```

OR

There is also another way to reduce the number of queries is use `select` instead of `pluck`, it will create sub-query instead pulling records from database. [Rails ActiveRecord Subqueries](https://rubyinrails.com/2018/02/23/rails-activerecord-subqueries/)

```
where.not(id: user.dismissed_notifications.select(:id))
```

Which will generate below SQL query

```
SELECT  `notifications`.* 
  FROM `notifications` 
  WHERE (
    `notifications`.`id` NOT IN 
      (SELECT `dismissed_notifications`.`id` 
        FROM `dismissed_notifications` 
        WHERE `dismissed_notifications`.`user_id` = 655
      )
  )
```